# DB2 Query for Hex Values

Tags: db2, hex, sql-like

Using DB2 version 10.5. I have a database table which I know has at least one row with bad xml data, which is affecting some other queries I'm trying to do. One of the rows has a #x1A character in it. I'm trying to find a way to do a query that will give me all rows that have invalid xml characters [#x0E-#x1F] in them. Below are several attempts I've tried, but they did not work.

```
SELECT
  e.EMLNAME
FROM MYDB.EMPLOYEE e
WHERE
  -- [#x0E-#x1F]
  /*
  e.EMLNAME like '%#x0E%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x0F%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x10%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x11%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x12%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x13%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x14%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x15%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x16%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x17%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x18%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x19%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x1A%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x1B%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x1C%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x1D%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x1E%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%#x1F%';

  e.EMLNAME like '%\x0E%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x0F%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x10%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x11%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x12%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x13%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x14%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x15%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x16%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x17%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x18%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x19%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x1A%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x1B%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x1C%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x1D%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x1E%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\x1F%';

  e.EMLNAME like '%\0x0E%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x0F%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x10%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x11%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x12%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x13%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x14%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x15%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x16%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x17%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x18%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x19%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x1A%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x1B%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x1C%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x1D%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x1E%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%\0x1F%';
  */

  e.EMLNAME like '%0x0E%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x0F%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x10%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x11%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x12%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x13%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x14%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x15%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x16%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x17%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x18%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x19%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x1A%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x1B%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x1C%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x1D%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x1E%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%0x1F%';
```

Any pointers on how I can query for the hex values? I tried to do each hex value individually as I don't know of a way to do a range. If there is a way to do a range, that would be an even better solution.

Comment: More recent versions of DB2 have a REGEXP_LIKE() function which would allow searching for range(s) or set(s) of characters in a single search.

Comment: What are you planning to do once you find them? May be you should just simply `update MYDB.EMPLOYEE set e.EMLNAME = translate(e.EMLNAME, ' ', x'1a')`?

Comment: @mustaccio, plan to have reports showing the bad data. My guess is that business will eventually want the bad characters removed so '' instead of ' '.

Comment: I guess you could still use `translate()`, something like `...where length(translate(e.EMLNAME, '', x'0f0e1a10...')) < length(e.EMLNAME)`

Answer (score 4):

So I got the following to work:

```
SELECT
  e.EMLNAME
FROM MYDB.EMPLOYEE e
WHERE
  e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'0E'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'0F'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'10'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'11'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'12'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'13'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'14'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'15'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'16'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'17'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'18'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'19'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'1A'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'1B'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'1C'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'1D'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'1E'), '%')
  OR e.EMLNAME like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', x'1F'), '%');
```

Posting the answer, so others have an idea of what I'm looking for. I'll wait a while to see if anyone comes up with a cleaner solution. If they do, I'll accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

little variation of Venom

```
  SELECT e.EMLNAME FROM MYDB.EMPLOYEE e
  WHERE
  e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'0E' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'0F' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'10' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'11' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'12' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'13' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'14' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'15' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'16' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'17' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'18' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'19' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'1A' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'1B' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'1C' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'1D' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'1E' || '%'
  OR e.EMLNAME like '%' || x'1F' || '%';
```

Comment: Cleaner version of the concats, thx. I'm going to wait to see if anyone finds a way to do a range instead of having to list each item explicitly.